# How work this for loop code (logic)? PHP

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I do not understand the logic of this code. If $ i <5 why not print 5 times * but throw out only one * in first row?

```
$n = 5;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
  for ($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) {
    echo ' * ';
  }
  echo '<br>';
}
for ($i = $n; $i >= 1; $i--) {
  for ($j = 1; $j <= $i; $j++) {
    echo ' * ';
  }
  echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Can you post the right code for PHP? That looks crazy.

Comment: Code is post I am forgot sorry. Look again

Comment: Because $i is 1, and the second loop only runs as long as $j<=$i is true …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is very simple. Look at the first for loop. You have a for loop inside the for loop so as soon as your outer for loop begins, you're inner for loop will also be executed.

For eg,

[FIRST ITERATION] - Your outer for loop starts with $i = 1, so your inner for loop will consider the value of $i as 1 and the inner loop is executed because $j <= $i will be true. So only 1 * is printed.

[SECOND ITERATION] - Your outer for loop starts with $i = 2, so your inner for loop will consider the value of $i as 2 and the inner loop is executed twice because $j <= $i will be true both times as the conditions 1 <= 2 and 2 <= 2 will both return true. So 2 stars(*) are printed.

[THIRD ITERATION] - Your outer for loop starts with $i = 3, so your inner for loop will consider the value of $i as 3 and the inner loop is executed thrice because $j <= $i will be true all the three times as the conditions 1 <= 3, 2 <= 3 and 3 <= 3 will all return true. So 3 stars(*) are printed.

[FOURTH ITERATION] - Your outer for loop starts with $i = 4, so your inner for loop will consider the value of $i as 4 and the inner loop is executed four times because $j <= $i will be true all the four times as the conditions 1 <= 4, 2 <= 4, 3 <= 4 and 4 <= 4 will all return true. So 4 stars(*) are printed.

[FIFTH ITERATION] - Your outer for loop starts with $i = 5, so your inner for loop will consider the value of $i as 5 and the inner loop is executed five times because $j <= $i will be true all the five times as the conditions 1 <= 5, 2 <= 5, 3 <= 5, 4 <= 5 and 5 <= 5 will all return true. So 5 stars(*) are printed.

SECOND OUTER FOR LOOP LOGIC:

[FIRST ITERATION] - Your outer for loop starts with $i = 5, so your inner for loop will consider the value of $i as 5 and the inner loop is executed five times because $j <= $i will be true all the five times as the conditions 1 <= 5, 2 <= 5, 3 <= 5, 4 <= 5 and 5 <= 5 will all return true. So 5 stars(*) are printed.

[SECOND ITERATION] - Your outer for loop starts with $i = 4, so your inner for loop will consider the value of $i as 4 and the inner loop is executed four times because $j <= $i will be true all the four times as the conditions 1 <= 4, 2 <= 4, 3 <= 4 and 4 <= 4 will all return true. So 4 stars(*) are printed.

[THIRD ITERATION] - Your outer for loop starts with $i = 3, so your inner for loop will consider the value of $i as 3 and the inner loop is executed thrice because $j <= $i will be true all the three times as the conditions 1 <= 3, 2 <= 3 and 3 <= 3 will all return true. So 3 stars(*) are printed.

[FOURTH ITERATION] - Your outer for loop starts with $i = 2, so your inner for loop will consider the value of $i as 2 and the inner loop is executed twice because $j <= $i will be true both times as the conditions 1 <= 2 and 2 <= 2 will both return true. So 2 stars(*) are printed.

[FIFTH ITERATION] - Your outer for loop starts with $i = 5, so your inner for loop will consider the value of $i as 5 and the inner loop is executed because $j <= $i will be true. So only 1 * is printed.

Remember that your second outer for loop is not incrementing but it is decremented by one each time you loop is executed. So it starts with 5 and ends with 1.

Comment: This is veryy powerfull example. Thanks man.

Comment: if you can explain to me the other part of the loop, but also how you explained the first part. Thank you. I'll vote

Comment: Post Edited to include the second outer for loop logic as well.

Comment: Which for print * ? 
$i or $j ?
Thank

Answer (score 0):

You start with a main counter `$i` that runs for each row. It starts at 1 and will stop when it reaches 5 (included) so you will get 5 lines.

Inside that loop you have a star counter `$j` that starts at 1 and stops when it reaches `$i`'s value (included). So here are the iterations it does :

#### When `$i == 1` :

- Iteration 1: `$j == 1` : it prints `*`
- `$j == $i` : the loop stops and prints `<br />`

#### When `$i == 2` :

- Iteration 1: `$j == 1` : it prints `*`
- Iteration 2: `$j == 2` : it prints `*`
- `$j == $i` : the loop stops and prints `<br />`

#### When `$i == 3` :

- Iteration 1: `$j == 1` : it prints `*`
- Iteration 2: `$j == 2` : it prints `*`
- Iteration 3: `$j == 3` : it prints `*`
- `$j == $i` : the loop stops and prints `<br />`

... And so on until `$i == 5` and the loop prints 5 stars before printing `<br />`

Then you have a second loop where `$i` starts at 5 and goes down to 1 included (so it will run 5 times) and the inner loop is the same as the first one so it will print as many stars as the value of `$i` per line. The successive values of `$i` are 5, 4, 3, 2 then 1 so your script prints 5 stars then 4 then 3 then 2 then 1.

#### Result :

The code you posted prints the following :

```
*
*  *
*  *  *
*  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *
*  *  *
*  *
*
```

Just as expected.

If that's not what you expected of your script, please describe the expected behaviour so we can tell you what part should change.